# Jsoup parsing error with android

Tags: android, jsoup

I am reading data from my colleges website(html) using jsoup to display structured data in android app.

i am using this following code

```
Elements elements=doc.getElementsByClass("maintable").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(0).getElementById("table3").getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");
```

here is the image what i have to display 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SatlT.png)

html code is

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" style="width:101%;" class="maintable" id="table5">
        <tbody><tr class="parent" title="Please Click Here To View The Content">
        <td colspan="4" class="MTTD1" align="center"><b><u>Personal Details</u></b></td>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s ="<table border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"width:101%;\" class=\"maintable\" id=\"table5\">\n" +
                "        <tbody><tr class=\"parent\" title=\"Please Click Here To View The Content\">\n" +
                "        <td colspan=\"4\" class=\"MTTD1\" align=\"center\"><b><u>Personal Details</u></b></td>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
        Element elements = doc.select("table").first();
        for (Element element :elements.select("tr")){
            System.out.println(element.text());
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Personal Details
```

Comment: soorapadman check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001151/i-have-to-retrieve-data-from-html-table-using-jsoup

Comment: @user7449462 if you still didn't get the output share the HTML of the following question i ll update you with a answer